# Ui-select : dropdown larger than select

Tags: css, angularjs, ui-select

I want to use the ui-select component. But I am getting a weird behaviour, the dropdown area is larger than the select.

I am not an expert in CSS, if someone can help me on this, that would be nice.

I am posting the css that goes with it (when I click on the dropdown via Chrome webtool, code inspector)

```
element.style {
}
.select2-drop.select2-with-searchbox.select2-drop-active {
}
.select2-drop-active {
border-color: #66afe9;
}
.select2-drop-active {
border: 1px solid #5897fb;
border-top: none;
}
.select2-drop {
width: 100%;
margin-top: -1px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 9999;
top: 100%;
background: #fff;
color: #000;
border: 1px solid #aaa;
border-top: 0;
border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
box-shadow: 0 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}
.select2-container, .select2-drop, .select2-search, .select2-search input {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheetdiv {
display: block;
}
Pseudo ::before element
*:before, *:after {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
Pseudo ::after element
*:before, *:after {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
Inherited from div.col-md-7.ui-select-container.select2.select2-container.ng-pristine.ng-valid.select2-allowclear.select2-container-active.select2-dropdown-open.open
.select2-container {
margin: 0;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
zoom: 1;
vertical-align: middle;
margin-left: -12px;
}
Inherited from div#tab1.tab-pane.active
.tab-content > .active {
display: block;
visibility: visible;
}
.tab-content > .tab-pane {
display: none;
visibility: hidden;
}
Inherited from body.ng-scope.modal-open
body {
background-color: #e4e6e9;
min-height: 100%;
padding-bottom: 0;
font-family: 'Open Sans';
font-size: 13px;
color: #393939;
line-height: 1.5;
}
body {
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.42857143;
color: #333333;
background-color: #ffffff;
}
body {
background: #fafafa;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
color: #333;
}
Inherited from html.js.flexbox.flexboxlegacy.canvas.canvastext.webgl.no-touch.geolocation.postmessage.websqldatabase.indexeddb.hashchange.history.draganddrop.websockets.rgba.hsla.multiplebgs.backgroundsize.borderimage.borderradius.boxshadow.textshadow.opacity.cssanimations.csscolumns.cssgradients.cssreflections.csstransforms.csstransforms3d.csstransitions.fontface.generatedcontent.video.audio.localstorage.sessionstorage.webworkers.applicationcache.svg.inlinesvg.smil.svgclippaths
html {
font-size: 10px;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
html {
font-family: sans-serif;
-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

code of the ui-select 

                                                    {{$select.selected.nom}}

It seems that when I remove : class="col-md-7" the problem disappear. But I need it as I am working in a bootstrap grid.

Thanks in advance.
[image: UI-Select weird behaviour]

Comment: pb solved, I needed to surrong ui-select tag by <div class="col-md-7"></div>